# Is it possible to create a half dounat chart in Plotly.Js with multiple values

Tags: javascript, plotly.js

I would like to have something like this:
[image: Multi Line Half dounat]

I am not very versed in Plotly.js I tried

The Gauge implementation in plotly.js is pretty basic and does not seem to be posible to get to this.

I am also failing with dougnats due to inexperiance

Is it possible to do this or would I need something like D3.Js for this?